# Doctrine Migrations metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage on SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, pdo, doctrine

I've seen a large number of qusestions around this topic, however they all seem to relate to MariaDB and MySQL.  I am having this problem with SQLite.

I have a brand new Symfony 5.2 installation to try and narrow down this issue.  I have created 2 Entities, "User" and "Settings".  These are nothing major, just a couple of standard fields on each.

My $DATABASE_URL variable is defined as:

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/va/data.db"
```

My Doctrine config looks like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            datetime_immutable:
                class: \Carbon\Doctrine\DateTimeImmutableType
            datetime:
                class: \Carbon\Doctrine\DateTimeImmutableType
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: pdo_sqlite
                override_url: false
                logging: true
                profiling: true
                profiling_collect_backtrace: false
                profiling_collect_schema_errors: true
                options: {  }
                mapping_types: {  }
                default_table_options: {  }
                slaves: {  }
                replicas: {  }
                shards: {  }
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: /path/to/app/src/Entity
                        prefix: App\Entity
                        alias: App
                        mapping: true
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: null
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: null
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: null
                class_metadata_factory_name: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
                default_repository_class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
                quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default
                entity_listener_resolver: null
                repository_factory: doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory
                hydrators: {  }
                filters: {  }
        proxy_dir: '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
        proxy_namespace: Proxies
        resolve_target_entities: {  }
```

And the Doctrine Migrations config:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        DoctrineMigrations: /path/to/app/migrations
    enable_profiler: true
    services: {  }
    factories: {  }
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: null
            version_column_name: null
            version_column_length: null
            executed_at_column_name: null
            execution_time_column_name: null
    migrations: {  }
    connection: null
    em: null
    all_or_nothing: false
    check_database_platform: true
    custom_template: null
    organize_migrations: false
```

I executed `doctrine:migrations:migrate` and it correctly created the DB file.  I have viewed the DB file in an SQLite viewer and it has the tables I expect, including the Doctrine Migrations metadata table.

All looks OK - but then... I try and access the app in my browser and get this exception:

> The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue.

Running the `doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage` command retuns Success and indicates all has been synced up.

Then running `doctrine:migrations:list` throws the exception again.

I can't figure out how to resolve this?

Any help appreciated!